# Sequelize: creating a copy of an instance with 'nested' instances

Tags: sequelize.js

If I have three tables: paths, steps and items
and paths have many steps (one:many relationship)
steps have many items (one:many relationship)

Does sequelize have a method I can use to create a new copy of a path and all its 'nested' items?

I know I could just take the data from the path and create another path with it, but then I would have to do the same with every nested step and item. Is there a simpler way to handle this?

Comment: To clarify, I don't want the new path to point to the same step instances. I want it to to have its own copy of those steps, so they can later update independently.

Comment: Here is the documentation for what you want http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#creating-with-associations